# XML javascript create function to get total of fields

Tags: javascript, xml

Im using XML Sorry
I have a few fields in my xml

```
    <field name="montext" type="text" sp="" db="">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data />
    </field>
    <field name="montext2" type="text" sp="" db="">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data />
    </field>
    <field name="montext3" type="text" sp="" db=">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data />
    </field>
    <field name="montotal" type="text" sp="" db=">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data />
    </field>
```

I want to be able to check each field and see if there is data in it. if there data in the field count it as ONE if not its 0.  so if "montext" and "montext3" has data in it. i want my "montotal" to say 2.

this is what i have so far.

```
function getTotal(){
    var i;
    i=0;
    if(document.getElementById("montext").value.length&gt;0)
    i++;
    if(document.getElementById("montext2").value.length&gt;0)
    i++;
    if(document.getElementById("montext3").value.length&gt;0)
    i++;

    document.getElementById("montotal").value=i

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Give them a class or same name and loop over getElementsByName or getElementsByClass

Comment: use html5 validation, giving each field a required attrib, then you can simply say: document.querySelectorAll("[value]:invalid")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all  `data` elements inside of your `field` elements, try :

```
 <div id="container">
  <field name="montext" type="text" sp="" db="">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data />
    </field>
    <field name="montext2" type="text" sp="" db="">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data />
    </field>
    <field name="montext3" type="text" sp="" db=">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data />
    </field>
  </div>
    <field name="montotal" type="text" sp="" db=">
        <label post="">Mon</label>
        <html size="8" />
        <data id="totalData" />
    </field>
```

in generic way with javascript :

```
function getTotal(){
    var total=0;
    //get the container
    var container = docuement.getElementById("container");
    //get all fields inside of the div container
    var fields = container.getElementsByTagName("field");
    for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
     //get all data tags inside of the current field
     total += fields[i].getElementsByTagName("data").length;
    }

    document.getElementById("totalData").innerHTML = total;

  }
```